# Construct complex sql for Linq DataContext's ExecuteCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in a database on an SQL Server 2008 R2 server.

Table1:

```
Id, Value, Date
```

Table2:

```
Id, Value, Date
```

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC 4 project that utilizes Linq to SQL for database operations. I need to build a SQL command for db.ExecuteCommand(). No database Procedure or Function needed.

The SQL command should get {Value} and {Date} from Table1 depending on the "Id" entered by the user from the View. Then update {Value} and {Date} from all matching rows in Table2  where Tabl2.{Id} = {Id} of user input.

Is ExecuteCommand able to handle complex SQL command like this? How to build the command then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE table2 SET value = (SELECT value from table1 WHERE ID = {0})", userEnteredId);
```

Comment: Thanks artm. It worked perfectly with "Value" but do I need to write another update for "Date". Can both of "Value" and "Date" be set in one Select clause? Once this is answered I will flip it as "accepted".

Comment: I got it solved. "UPDATE table2 SET Value = TMP.Value, Date = TMP.Date FROM (SELECT Value, Date FROM table1 WHERE ID = {0}) AS TMP"